# Automate execute command

Tags: shell, terminal

I found myself doing this all the time:

```
open terminal 
cd /mydir/folder
parse deploy
```

Is it possible to create some kind of file I can click on, that does this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create file run.sh and run - `chmod +x run.sh`

The file should look like this -

`#!/bin/bash
cd /mydir/folder
parse deploy`